# MVC6 Prevent Redirect on unauthorized

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core-mvc, unauthorized

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 6 Web API app, with AngularJs frontend.

When I leave a session to decade, or I'm trying to call a Web API action unauthorized, I expect to receive a 401 status code.
Instead, I get a 302, and tries to redirect to the default path for login ("/Account/Login").

So I need to handle this in Angular.

From other forum posts here and googling I found that some people resolved their problems using in startup.cs:

```
services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(options =>
 {
     options.LoginPath = PathString.Empty;
});
```

No luck for me.

I use Identity as authentication backend and even adding

```
services.ConfigureIdentityApplicationCookie(options =>
{
     options.LoginPath = PathString.Empty;
});
```

does not give me the expected result. ASP.NET docs suggest this way to return a 401.

Using 1.0.0-beta7 CLR x86, IIS Express.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it worked to just set the AutometicAuthenticate to false.

```
   services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticAuthenticate = false;
            options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticChallenge = false;
            options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = PathString.Empty;
       });
```

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT**: the solution proposed by @EZI is correct.
Below my answer, which doesn't work on recent release.

Finally! I found the solution!

To be complete, I started with this comment found on source code in aspnet/Identity github.

```
// If the LoginPath is null or empty, the middleware will not look for 401 Unauthorized status codes, and it will not redirect automatically when a login occurs.
```

which give me the wrong directions.

Digging with debug on ConfigureIdentityApplicationCookie' options, I found that there is a delegate on "Notifications" property

```
OnApplyRedirect
```

Bingo!

Now I can control the redirect.

```
services.ConfigureIdentityApplicationCookie(options =>
{
     options.LoginPath = PathString.Empty;
     options.Notifications = new CookieAuthenticationNotifications {  
         OnApplyRedirect = context => { context.Response.StatusCode = 401; } 
     };
});
```

This maybe isn't a good way to handle the problem, but finally I receive a 401 Unauthorized when the web.api action is called without authentication.

Comment: Does someone have information about how to solve in release version of asp.net core?

Comment: This seems to work for me: `services.AddIdentity<myUser, IdentityRole>(c => c.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = PathString.Empty`

Answer (score 1):

my solution was similar to @Ezi

Confirmed working for RC2

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
    {
        options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticChallenge = false;
    });
```