# Why am I automatically pushed to login page when a user is unauthenticated by calling the Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, http-status-code-401, authorize

I am using MVC 6 web api and I have a method (shown below).  When the user is not authenticated (logged on) and makes the call (example url: https://localhost:44338/api/account/Test), they get automatically pushed to url:

https://localhost:44338/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2Faccount%2FTest

BUT this is a web api project and does not have any views (such as im automatically getting pushed to here).

Code:

```
    [HttpGet("test")]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
    {
        return Json("success");
    }
```

Why am I getting automatically pushed to the login page?  I've NOTHING in my startup.cs or web.config that specifies this.  It seems like default behaviour?  How do I disable this so I just get the 401 status?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to say, I'm using MVC 6 which is ASP.net Core 1 :-)

Comment: You should also use the correct tags then

Comment: I've amended the tags now

Comment: Check out the answers here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34770886/mvc6-unauthorized-results-in-redirect-instead

Comment: This reference had the correct solution for me!  Thanks a million for passing that on @TrevorWard :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience, here's the solution that worked for me:

```
      services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(o =>
        {
            o.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
            {
                OnRedirectToLogin = ctx =>
                {
                    if (ctx.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                    {
                        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
                    }
                    ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
                }
            };
        });
```

I was pointed to this article: [mvc6 unauthorized results in redirect instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34770886/mvc6-unauthorized-results-in-redirect-instead)  by @TrevorWard

Answer (score 0):

1. ASP.NET automatically redirects to the login page, if you have AuthorizationAttribute defined in your `App_Start/FilterConfig.cs`, see if `AuthorizeAttribute()` is defined. If it does, remove it.
2. Check if you have `App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs`. If it does, delete it.
3. If Startup.cs is decorated with the attribute `[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(FleetSys.Startup))]`, remove that attribute.

Comment: using MVC 6 here, so need the equivalent in ASP.net Core 1

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using wrong Authorize attribute.

In MVC, you should use System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute and that one will redirect.

In Web API, you should use System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute and that one will return 401 status code.