# Suppress redirect on API URLs in ASP.NET Core

Tags: authentication, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-2, http-redirect

I have an ASP.NET Core site that uses cookie authentication for most pages. For those pages, the default server response of providing a 302 redirect for an unauthorized client is desirable. However, the site also accepts API requests; they use API keys and have no use for cookies.

Ideally, I'd like to turn off cookie processing for the API URLs altogether, but minimally, I need to ensure that if an API client is unauthorized, the server doesn't respond with a 302 redirect.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Replace the redirect event handler with one that uses the default behavior only if the path is not an API. In `Startup.ConfigureServices`, add this:

```cs
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
    options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = ReplaceRedirector(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied);
    options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = ReplaceRedirector(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin);
});
```

Use this helper method to replace the redirect methods:

```cs
static Func<RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, Task> ReplaceRedirector(HttpStatusCode statusCode, Func<RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, Task> existingRedirector) =>
    context => {
        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api")) {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)statusCode;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        return existingRedirector(context);
    };
```

With this in place, the API controller methods can call `Unauthorized()` and `Forbid()` without causing redirects.

*Update:* The above is for ASP.NET Core 2. The [code for ASP.NET Core 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42030138/2) is different.

Comment: +1. It should be noted that the `services.ConfigureApplicationCookie()` call should come *after* the call that sets up your authentication (in my case `services.AddIdentity()`), otherwise these settings will be overwritten

Comment: This seems to be a really clean way when used with spa.

Comment: I tried to implement your solution in my .NET Core 3.0 Web API project, but without success. It seems the action delegate parameter that is passed to `ConfigureApplicationCookie` is never called; I set a breakpoint on its first line, but it's never hit. And my test client app keeps getting HTTP status code 500 instead of 403 when my test API's controller calls `Forbid`. Any ideas?

Comment: Same problem here with .NET Core 3.1.  This code doesn't seem to work at all.  Any ideas?

Comment: This is a brilliant solution and can confirm it works with .NET Core 5.0

Answer (score 5):

For .net core 2.x here's a fix (based on Edward's answer) :

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
            {
                OnRedirectToAccessDenied = ReplaceRedirector(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, context => options.Events.RedirectToAccessDenied(context)),
                OnRedirectToLogin = ReplaceRedirector(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, context => options.Events.RedirectToLogin(context))
            };
        });
```

where `ReplaceRedirector`:

```
Func<RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, Task> ReplaceRedirector(HttpStatusCode statusCode, Func<RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, Task> existingRedirector) =>
context =>
{
    if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"))
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)statusCode;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    return existingRedirector(context);
};
```

Comment: I updated my answer to include ASP.NET Core 2. In my update, I didn't replace `Events`, but rather just set its relevant properties.

Answer (score 2):

Other simple way

```
 .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/401";
                options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                {
                    OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context => 
                    {
                        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"))
                        {
                            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                };
            })
```