# How to return 403 Forbidden response as IActionResult in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I would like to return a 403 Forbidden to the client when trying to perform a restricted operation. What is the method I need to use?

I searched over the internet but I found only these for MVC 5:

> If the return type for your web api method is HttpResponseMessage then
> you need to use the below code:
>
> ```
> return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "RFID is disabled for this site.");
> Or  if the return type for your web api method is IHttpActionResult then you need to use the below code
>
> return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden,"RFID is disabled for this site.");
> ```
>
> How to return 403 for IActionResult type:
>
> ```
> public IActionResult Put(string userid, [FromBody]Setting setting)
>  {
>     var result = _SettingsRepository.Update(userid, setting);
>     if (result == true)
>     {
>        return Ok(201);
>     }
>     else
>     {
>        return BadRequest();
>     }
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 169, accepted):

When you want to respond with a HTTP 403 status and *allow* ASP.NET Core's authentication logic to handle the response with its forbidden handling logic (can be configured in your `Startup` class, and may cause a redirect to another page), use:

```
return Forbid();
```

(same applies to `Unauthorized()`)

---

When you want to respond with a HTTP 403 status code from an API and *do not want* the ASP.NET Core authentication logic to perform any redirect or other action, use:

```
return StatusCode(403);

// or with developer-friendly type
return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden);

// or as an api-friendly error response
return Problem(
    type: "/docs/errors/forbidden",
    title: "Authenticated user is not authorized.",
    detail: $"User '{user}' must have the Admin role.",
    statusCode: StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden,
    instance: HttpContext.Request.Path
);
```

The latter example produces a [client error response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#client-error-response).

Comment: a little bit cleaner version is `return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, messageOrSerializeableObject);`

Comment: Actually there is a simpler way than @MovGP0 suggests `return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden, <you object>);`

Comment: I was looking how to setup things in Startup.cs as mentioned by Bart, here is an interesting thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35656828/return-http-403-using-authorize-attribute-in-asp-net-core/35732477

Comment: BTW, you can use `Forbid()` and suppress the redirect by overwriting the authentication events as described here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42030138/968003.

Comment: [According to the documentation for `Problem(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.problemdetails), the `instance:` and `type:` parameters should be URIs that can be dereferenced to view human-readable details of the specific error, so while `type: "/docs/errors/forbidden"` is okay, that should be a working URI, but returning `HttpContext.Request.Path` for `instance:` is incorrect: instead, either omit that parameter (or use `null`) or store details of this specific error somewhere and expose those details via that URI.

Answer (score 28):

Alternative to MstfAsan's answer is to use:

```
return Forbid();
```

It is a method on the controller base class that does the same thing.

Or

```
return StatusCode(403);
```

If you want to return a message, then you must use `StatusCode`.

Comment: Note that in ASP.NET Core 2, returning a `ForbidResult` (as returned by `Forbid`) will trigger some kind of interaction with the framework's authentication code and - if you haven't set up authentication in a way that the framework understands - throw the error *"No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found."* If you don't want to integrate with ASP.NET Core's auth, stick to returning a `StatusCodeResult` to avoid this error.

Comment: Using Forbid() in an Api controller will try to redirect to Acccout/AccessDenied even after I changed the DefaultForbidScheme. Only StatusCode(403) seems to work correctly.

Answer (score 11):

Simply you can use ObjectResult to return a custom response with a status code.

See the syntax,

```
return new ObjectResult("Message") {StatusCode = YOUR_STATUS_CODE };
```

**Note -**
You can pass an object also,

```
return new ObjectResult(your_model) {StatusCode = YOUR_STATUS_CODE };
```

**Example:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] SomeData _data)
{
     // do your stuff

    // return forbidden with custom message
    return new ObjectResult("Forbidden") { StatusCode = 403};
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use  `return new ForbidResult();` Class declaration is

```
public class ForbidResult : ActionResult, IActionResult
```

For more spesific usages visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.forbidresult

Comment: Interestingly, ForbidResult does not inherit from StatusCodeResult, at least in ASP NET CORE 2.2.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't return `IActionResult` as result, you can use the following code :

```
public List<SomeModel> GetModels()
{
   ... 
   ... // check logic
   ...

   Response.StatusCode = 403;
   return new List<SomeModel>();
}
```

Comment: This is the answer I was seeking.  Coming from Java & Node we typically specify the intended object as part of the method signature, not a generic IActionResult.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Having the same issue when migrate from asp net mvc to net core 5. As a decision you can inherit from ObjectResult:

```
public class ForbidActionResult : ObjectResult
{
    public ForbidActionResult(int statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, string errorMessage = null) : 
        base(errorMessage ?? "User is not allowed to enter this page."))
    {
        StatusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public override async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        await base.ExecuteResultAsync(context);
    }
}
```

and return it as IActionResult:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get(int bookId)
{
    var book = dbContext.BookRepository.Find(bookId);

    if (!CurrentUser.CanEditAsClient(book))
    {
        return new ForbidActionResult();
    }

    return Ok();
}
```