# Forbid() returns 404

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0

I have returned `Forbid()` from a web request, and the browser claims its receiving a 404 instead of a 403.

I have added a handler to the cookie authentication like so...

```
o.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied += ctx =>
{
   ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;

   return Task.FromResult(0);
};
```

But this doesn't appear to be called.

Thus, why is a method that should return a 403 returning a 404?

Answer (score 3):

The `Forbid()` command seems to have an internal ASP.NET MVC controller redirect handling. In case you only want to provide a classic API and want 403 to be returned you should switch the command to

```
return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden);
```

Don't forget to import the using

```
using static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes;
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47708867/828184

So far I'm not aware if this behaviour of `Forbid()` could be changed.

Comment: This is the real answer to the problem. Works for me. (The other answer didn't apply.)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. These were my steps to fix it:

1. Temporarily remove all the exception handling like `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error")` from `Startup`. In my case the `404` happened because the exception handling was broken.
2. Then I got the "real" error: My problem was that I had no authentication configured, and therefore no authentication schemes.

After I added the correct authentication options to `Startup` (in my case I used a custom authentication handler) I got the correct response code:

```
services.AddAuthentication(LicenseKeyAuthenticationOptions.Scheme)
        .AddScheme<LicenseKeyAuthenticationOptions, LicenseKeyAuthenticationHandler>(LicenseKeyAuthenticationOptions.Scheme, null);
```