# WebClient UploadData does not throw on 403

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to call my .NET Core API with the following code:

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    try
    {
        webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(updateLiveMapRequest);
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        await webClient.UploadDataTaskAsync("http://localhost:1778/api/upload/data", data);
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        Logger.Debug(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

On my server I, for testing purposes, simply return `Forbid()`:

```
return Forbid();
```

The call reaches the controller, however the consuming web client is totally happy with getting a 403 as a result and does not throw an exception like it does on `BadRequest`.

Why is that?

Comment: Any reason for using the deprecated `WebClient` instead of the preferred `HttpClient`?

Comment: Habit, I assume. Didn't know there was a preferred new one :)

Comment: `HttpClient` has a `IsSuccessStatusCode` property that returns false for any non-`2XX` status. `EnsureSuccessStatusCode` will throw an exception based on `IsSuccessStatusCode`

Comment: Alright, will give that a spin. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured this out thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45095853/how-to-return-403-forbidden-response-as-iactionresult-in-asp-net-core-mvc-1-1-3) answer:

> When you want to respond with a HTTP 403 status code from an API and
>   do not want the ASP.NET Core authentication logic to perform any
>   redirect or other action, use:

This will do the trick:

```
return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
```