# Returning 403 from a strongly typed method

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

Somewhat similar to [How to return 403 Forbidden response as IActionResult in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45095853/how-to-return-403-forbidden-response-as-iactionresult-in-asp-net-core)

.NET Core 6, WebAPI application, C#. I've got a REST method registered with `MapGet`. It's strongly typed, returns an instance of my data record class which the framework then serializes and emits automagically. If I want to return error 403, and potentially an alternative error object, is there a way to do so **without breaking the strong typing**?

One approach I've considered is injecting `IHttpContextAccessor` and building the response with status and content, but there is probably a better way.

Comment: You can throw an exception and have some middleware catch it and return the 403.  Or Maybe the more generic version of IActionResult, IActionResult<T>: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionresult-1?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Sorry, it's actually `ActionResult<YourClass>` as the return type.    Then just return `Forbid(new YourClass())`.

Comment: Went with the former. `ActionResult` wraps the result.