# Forbid() returns error 404 instead of 403 and StatusCode(403) succeeds in returning 403

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http

I am working on a Q&A web platform and I was trying to implement authorization that only the owners of a question/answer/vote/etc. can update or delete this or of course, an admin. Indeed, the authorization works fine, users cand delete their staff, admin can do it too, but the problem appears when I try to update a question being logged into another user's account. Normally, I would expect an Error 403 : Forbidden, but instead I get 404.

The thing is, if I change the Forbid() with StatusCode(403), I don't get 404 anymore and get the desired response, but I think Forbid() is more appropriate for my problem. I will leave my code here, but I think the problem is from somewhere else in my project.

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateQuestion(int id, QuestionUpdateDto questionUpdateDto)
{
    var question = await _context.Questions.FindAsync(id);
    if (question == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var currentUserId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    var currentUser = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(currentUserId);
    var isAdmin = await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(currentUser, "Admin");

    if (question.UserId != currentUserId && !isAdmin)
    {
        return Forbid();
    }

    question.Title = questionUpdateDto.Title;
    question.Content = questionUpdateDto.Content;
    // Continue updating other fields as necessary

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return NoContent();
}
```

Here is how I added Authentication service in the Program.cs file:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
```

Comment: Is your bearer token middleware also checking that the client owns the resource?

Comment: Umm, not quite sure about that. How should it look like?

Comment: According to you, anyone who's an owner of the question or an admin can do the update. That means, if the logged in user is not the owner of the question OR if the logged in user is not an admin, the logged in user gets the Forbid(). Is this correct?

Comment: @SoftwareDveloper that is correct, and the Forbid() gets hit but still get error 404. And as i said, if I change Forbid with StatusCode(403), when StatusCode(403) gets hit, it succeeds in returning the error 403 instead of 404.

Comment: When you add the bearer token middleware at startup, it's part of the `services.AddAuthentication` call. Are you providing a delegate in which you assign an `Events` property with an `On<something>` property where you do some of your own checks?  I know that's vague, but that's as specific as I can get because it can vary, or not even be there.

Comment: @madreflection okay, done. Is it the problem caused by my Authentication service or the problem might be caused by something else?

Comment: Unfortunately, that new block of code didn't have what I was expecting to see.  I'd have to set up a project from scratch to test it. Hopefully, someone who's more familiar with it will see the question.

Comment: @madreflection if you are down we can join discord or something in order to show you the entire project and take a better look at what is happening exactly.

Comment: Do you have a requirement to use `Forbid()` instead of returning a 403 status code?  [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47708867/886945) suggests APIs can just return a status code.

Comment: @SteveWong from what i understood StatusCode(403) just returns an error to the user, but Forbid() implies more of a friendly response informing the user that he is not allowed to perform that action or other staff like this. And I thought that a behaviour like this is more appropriate for my application than just an error 403 popping up.