# .Net core custom middleware - How to come out with Forbidden error and goto Error controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have custom authentication and authorization handlers, but there is still a custom middleware to check few other things on another scenario. Here is some code for exception handler

```
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/{0}");
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
```

The custom middleware code is below. This is a test code. I want to come out of the middleware on some conditions. The below code does not work (it won't go to error controller). When I use response.Redirect(), it works, but then it goes on infinite redirects. I've thought of return Forbid(), return StatusCodeResult(403), but the return type is Task.

```
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
          

        await _next(context);
        return;
```

Comment: There are similar questions like https://stackoverflow.com/q/42030137/125981 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/45095853

Comment: I read that just before posting this question. The difference is the custom middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following and it worked. I think the complete call will stop it from executing the rest of the middleware and go back to the exceptionhandler registered at the top. When I tried to set the StatusCode after the await _next(context) call, it interestingly had the response from the page that was requested appended by the response form the error handler.

```
context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
await context.Response.CompleteAsync();

//await _next(context);
return;
```